# Importance of 2nd or 3rd order RC Low Pass Filter in noise/ripple filtering

Tags: filter, low-pass

I dont quite understand what importance does having a 2nd or 3rd order RC Lowpass filter do to filtering power rail noises. If the first stage filter only allows frequencies below 15.9 Hz arent the other stages unnecessary? Adding more series resistance to the rail will always not benefit the load since it would be receiving slightly less voltage.

Does adding more stages equate to less noise than the previous one ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frB4Qz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have an error in your diagram. The cutoff frequency of the second stage filter is actually 1.59kHz, not 15.9kHz.

Comment: iirc the "order" of a filter essentially dictates how sharply the filter rolls off. Higher order falls off more steeply. The ideal filter would be a square shape. No realizable filter can do that.

Comment: The latter stages load the prior stages. So, you need to solve:$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_O}{R_3} + s\: C_3\: V_O &= \frac{V_Y}{R_3}\tag{$V_O$}\\\\
\frac{V_Y}{R_2} + \frac{V_Y}{R_3} + s\: C_2\:V_Y &= \frac{V_X}{R_2} + \frac{V_O}{R_3}\tag{$V_Y$}\\\\
\frac{V_X}{R_1} + \frac{V_X}{R_2} + s\: C_1\:V_X &=\frac{V_I}{R_1} + \frac{V_Y}{R_2}\tag{$V_X$}
\end{align*}$$where \$V_X\$ is the left node and \$V_Y\$ is the middle node, for$$\frac{V_\text{O}}{V_\text{I}}$$From that you can work out the actual behavior.

Comment: I've never seen a power rail filter like the one in your question - it will be really ineffective. Where did you find the circuit and what made you think it is suitable as a power filter (it isn't).

Comment: I have something like this on my guitar tube amp, coming from transformer through tube fullwave rectifier.

Comment: @jonk thats what i thought too that the other resistor would interfere with the others. hence i would remove them.

Comment: @Andyaka just from reading around this seems to be a common answer, no actual purpose yet. I like this approach its litterally just a resistor and a capacitor. Taking this a step further I even saw a video about a ["capacitance multiplier"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wopmEyZKnYo) which combines RC filter with a transistor supposedly makes a very clean supply

Comment: @Jakequin a capacitance multiplier IS NOT a filter for power rail noise and neither is the RC network shown in your question.

Comment: @Andyaka Im sorry i do not get it, can you elaborate what you mean

Comment: @Jake your question is asking if a 2nd or 3rd order low pass filter is important for filtering power rails - and my answer is that I strongly believe there to be no importance and also no connection with power rails. You also imply that adding more resistance is somehow a benefit to the load but it isn't. LC filters are used to clean up power rails in almost every case that I've seen. So I'm questioning the validity of your question and that would make answers somewhat misled. Now if you were talking about filtering a signal it would be of more use but not with the values you have proposed.

Comment: @Andyaka i see now where one of the misunderstanding comes from, I ment NOT benifit the load, a low 10 mA load would already drop 1V on a 100ohm resistor which is not good in any way. An yes the point of my question is what is the importance of 2nd and 3rd in cleaning filters in cleaning the rails since the bulk of the cleaning is done on the 1st stage. I apologize if i have not made it clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the second and third stages are there to deal with self-resonance issues in the capacitors. (So this really isn't a "third-order filter", for any practical purposes.)

If the capacitors were ideal capacitors, then the second and third stages would have no appreciable effect. In an ideal capacitor, the impedance of the capacitor keeps getting lower as the frequency gets higher.

In the real world, all capacitors have some parasitic inductance. At low frequencies, this effect of this parasitic inductance is inconsequential, so the impedance-vs-frequency relationship resembles an ideal capacitor. But at higher frequencies the effect of the parasitic inductance becomes more and more significant (the capacitor actually looks like an inductor-capacitor "LC" circuit). At some point there will be a resonant frequency just like with any other LC circuit, and beyond that frequency *the impedance of the capacitor will increase as frequency increases*, just like an inductor. At this point the low-pass filter is no longer a low-pass filter!

https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2019-capacitor-self-resonant-frequency-and-signal-integrity

As you'd probably imagine, larger capacitors have a lower self-resonant frequency and smaller capacitors have a higher self-resonant frequency. So, it is a common practice to put multiple capacitors in parallel -- for example a 0.1µF capacitor in parallel with a 10µF capacitor -- to overcome this effect. Once the frequency gets high enough that the 10µF capacitor is no longer effective, the 0.1µF capacitor is still acting as an effective capacitor so the circuit overall still works.

The extra resistors in this circuit are new to me, but as this article suggests perhaps they are there to dampen out other resonant effects that could happen otherwise.

https://incompliancemag.com/article/using-capacitors-in-parallel-dangerous/

Comment: Spot-on with the answer. I also think the added resistors are teacher-speak to create more math. Parallel capacitors of equal and different values are common, but I have never seen added resistors. Normally specific value inductors would be used, if any at all.

Comment: Ahh so those resistors are just unnecessary. and the best circuit  to use would  be resistor paired with parallel capacitor

Answer (score 1):

The additional RC sections are useful to attenuate at very high frequencies, where the ESR and ESL of the first capacitor acts to set an attenuation floor.

With 100 ohms in the first section, and 0.1 ohm ESR, you get at most 60dB (1,000:1) attenuation at any frequency, even ignoring the ESL.

If you truly want 100dB attenuation, which would be a mere 5 decades above the F3dB of the first RC section, all these irksome parasitics have to be including in the thinking.